# Unable to debug app remotely - port isn't accessible externally

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

**I need to debug my app remotely, but I unable to do that, due to the following error:**

```
Unable to open debugger port (X.X.X.X:8000): java.net.ConnectException "Connection timed out: connect"
```

I have:

1. Java app running in Tomcat on a remote server (Debian)
2. IntelliJ Idea running locally (Windows)

I came to the conclusion that cause of problem is that **port 8000, used for remote debugging, is inaccessible via external ip, only via 'localhost'.** Following are causes, why I think so:

A remote debug is working on an expected port:

```
root@victor-app-server:/opt/tomcat-home/bin# netstat -tulpn | grep 8000
tcp  0  0  0.0.0.0:8000  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  3773/java
```

I able to telnet to it via 'localhost':

```
root@victor-app-server:/opt/tomcat-home/bin# telnet localhost 8000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

But unable to telnet via external ip:

```
root@victor-app-server:/opt/tomcat-home/bin# telnet X.X.X.X 8000
Trying X.X.X.X...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

Here is output of iptables:

```
root@victor-app-server:/opt/tomcat-home/bin# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**How can I fix this issue with 8000 port? Or maybe there is other cause to my main problem?**

Comment: I assume that the firewall on your debian server does not allow to connect to port 8000.

Comment: @Heri, I thought that since iptables contains no rules, firewall is not cause problem. If it is not so, then explain me, please, how to check firewall?

Comment: Where is the server? In LAN or external? If the server is in another LAN, is the configuration of the router in the LAN to which the server is connected proper?

Answer (score 1):

This is the command that did the trick for me:

`sudo ufw allow <debug_port>`

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem via Java 11 and address property such as these JVM arguments:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=6565
```

However my problem is solved by change value of address property like this sample:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:6565
```

Now 6565 port is accessible externally.

Answer (score 0):

Try "iptables -F" which unblocks the firewalls