# Cannot connect to the remote server via Intellij for debug

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot

I have a remote Linux server and an application on it which I need to debug. I start the .jar file through the terminal in Intellij with line:

`sudo java -Dspring.profiles.active=test -Dspring.config.additional-location=file:/.../external.properties -Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005 -jar /.../JARFILE.jar`

Jar file is started correctly, the application is working, but I cannot debug it remotely via IDEA with those settings: [remote debugging configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvY0X.png).

It throws an error saying `"java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect."` after a few seconds from I clicked the debug button.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that you are unable to connect to the JVM via a debugger.

I'd expect that the reason for this error is the fact that you are not launching the JVM with the correct input arguments so that it can run in `debug` mode.

The easiest fix for this issue would be to allow IntelliJ to run it for you with correct configuration.

You say that you want to deploy the app to a remote server and debug it from there. Why not use [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html) functionality in IntelliJ, which will guarantee that correct flags are set.

I think this value `address=*:5005` might be wrong, try running it with `address=5005`

Comment: the thing is that the app is already deployed and I just need to debug it

Comment: do I need to enter user credentials in debugging configuration?

Comment: No, you typically don't have to enter those. As you say, yes, it is deployed, but is it deployed with the right configuration which enables debugging ... or is the firewall open ... try some stuff from here ? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480048/unable-to-debug-app-remotely-port-isnt-accessible-externally

Comment: Are you able to connect to the app via a debugger when you it locally ? If yes, then its probably some firewall issue or something ...

Comment: Please upvote and accept my answer if it helped you ^__^